# When reading in a .txt file in c++, how do I change a number that's stored in the .txt file as "365048" to "36, 50, 48" using a dynamic array?

Tags: c++, class, file-io, header-files, dynamic-arrays

I have been trying to separate a number stored in a .txt file as "365048" to "36, 50, 48" when it has been read into my program using a dynamic array and i'm not sure where I am going wrong. The variable i'm having the issue with is int* purchases.

Code from Main.cpp

```
// Repeat_Assessment_C++_Aisling.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include "Customer.h"
using namespace std;

void OutputFileStream();
void parseLine(const string& str);
void InputFileStream();
//void printActions();


void OutputFileStream()
{
    cout << "Creating and writing to file: Customer.txt" << endl;

    ofstream outStream("customers.txt");  // write mode (overwrites existing data)

    if (outStream.good())
    {
        int customerID = 150033;
        outStream << "This is a line of text.\n";
        outStream << "This is another line of text.\n";
        outStream << "This is a line of text.\n";
        int numOfPurchases = 4;
        int purchases = 0;
        outStream << customerID << "Mr" << "Jack" << "New" << numOfPurchases << purchases << endl;

        outStream.close(); //  close file
        cout << "File written.\n" << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to open file";
}

void parseLine(const string& str) {

    stringstream strStream(str); //create string stream from the string
   // int customerID;
    string title;
    string name;
    string type;
    //int numOfPurchases;
    //int purchases;
    string s;
   
    int customerID = 150033;
    getline(strStream, s, ';');
    customerID = stoi(s);

    getline(strStream, title, ';');
    getline(strStream, name, ';');
    getline(strStream, type, ';');

    int numOfPurchases = 4;
    getline(strStream, s, ';');
    numOfPurchases = stoi(s);

    int purchases = 0;
    getline(strStream, s, ';');
    purchases = stoi(s);
    int* purchasesArray = new int[3];
    purchasesArray[0] = (purchases & (255 << 24)) >> 24;
    purchasesArray[1] = (purchases & (255 << 16)) >> 16;
    purchasesArray[2] = (purchases & (255 << 8)) >> 8;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int purchasesArray[3];
    }

    cout << " CustomerID: " << customerID << "Title:" << title << " Name: " << name << " Type:" << type << " Number of Purchases: " << numOfPurchases << "Purchases: " << purchases << endl;
}

void InputFileStream() {
    cout << "Reading from a semi-colon delimited txt file" << endl;

    string line;
    ifstream inStream("customers.txt"); //opens file as an input file stream
    if (inStream.good()) //if the file is opened successfully and not empty
    {
        while (getline(inStream, line)) //reads line until false return
        {
            parseLine(line);
        }
        inStream.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "unable to open file or the file is empty!";
}

int main()
{
     InputFileStream();

    Customer cust1;

    cust1.setCustomerID(150032);
    cust1.setTitle("Mr");
    cust1.setName("Joey");
    cust1.setNumOfPurchases(3);
    cust1.setPurchases(366, 352, 334);
    cust1.setType("New");

    cout << cust1.getCustomerID() << endl;
    cout << cust1.getTitle() << endl;
    cout << cust1.getName() << endl;
    cout << cust1.getNumOfPurchases() << endl;
    cout << cust1.getPurchases() << endl;
    cout <<  cust1.getType() << endl;
   
   


    return 0;
   

}
```

Code from Customer.h

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<string>

class Customer
{
private:
    int customerID;
    string title;
    string name;
    int numOfPurchases;
    int* purchases;
    string type;

public:
    Customer(); // default constructor
    Customer(int customerID, string title, string name, int numOfPurchases, int purchase1, int purchase2, int purchase3, string type);
    
    //copy overload assignment
    Customer& operator=(Customer& otherCustomer);
    Customer(const Customer& source);

    ~Customer(); //destructor

    //Getters and Setters
    void setCustomerID(int customerID);
    void setTitle(string title);
    void setName(string name);
    void setNumOfPurchases(int numOfPurchases);
    void setPurchases(int purchase1, int purchase2, int purchase3);
    void setType(string type);

    int getCustomerID();
    string getTitle();
    string getName();
    int getNumOfPurchases();
    int* getPurchases();
    string getType();

    void printCustomer() {
        cout << customerID << "," << title << "," << name << "," << numOfPurchases << "," << purchases << "," << type << endl;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Customer& customer); // overloaded operator<<
    friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, Customer& customer); // overloaded operator >>
};
```

Code from Customer.cpp

```
#include "Customer.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<utility>
using namespace std;

//default constructor
Customer::Customer() {
}


//Full constructor
Customer::Customer(int customerID, string title, string name, int numOfPurchases, int purchase1, int purchase2, int purchase3, string type)
{
    this->customerID = customerID;
    this->title = title;
    this->name = name;
    this->numOfPurchases = numOfPurchases;
    purchases = new int[3];
    purchases[0] = purchase1;
    purchases[1] = purchase2;
    purchases[2] = purchase3;
    this->type = type;
}

Customer::Customer(const Customer& source) //copy constructor
{
    cout << "copy constructor called" << endl;
    this->customerID = source.customerID;
    this->title = source.title;
    this->name = source.name;
    this->numOfPurchases = source.numOfPurchases;
    this->purchases = new int[3];
    purchases[0] = source.purchases[0];
    purchases[1] = source.purchases[1];
    purchases[2] = source.purchases[2];
    this->type = source.type;
}

//overloaded assignment operator=
Customer& Customer::operator= (Customer& otherCustomer)
{
    cout << "Overloaded assignment operator= called" << endl;

    //self-assignment guard
    if (this == &otherCustomer)
        return *this;  //refernce to the same object

   // copy data from the source (rhs) to this object (the destination)
    name = otherCustomer.name;

    //must make a new scores object to store a copy of the other student 
    if (purchases != nullptr)
        delete[] purchases;

    purchases = new int[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        purchases[i] = otherCustomer.purchases[i];
    }

    //return this existing object so we can chain this operator 
    return *this;
}
Customer::~Customer() {
    cout << "Destructor ~Customer called" << endl;
    delete[] purchases;
}

// Overloaded insertion operator  (Outputs Character object data as an output stream)
// Defined in header file as a  "friend" function, as it is not a member function
//
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Customer& customer)
{
    cout << "Customer details ( output by insertion operator<< )" << endl;
    cout << "Customer ID: " << customer.customerID << endl;
    cout << "Title: " << customer.title << endl;
    cout << "Name: " << customer.name << endl;
    cout << "Number of purchases: " << customer.numOfPurchases << endl;
    cout << "Purchases: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0) cout << ",";
        cout << customer.purchases[i];
    }
    cout << "Type: " << customer.type << endl;
    
    return out;
}


istream& operator>> (istream& in, Customer& customer)
{
    cout << "Enter Customer details ( using the extraction operator>> )" << endl;
    cout << "Enter Customer ID: " << endl;
    cin >> customer.customerID;
    cout << "Enter Title: " << endl;
    getline(cin, customer.title);
    cout << "Enter Name: " << endl;
    getline(cin, customer.name);
    cout << "Enter Number of Purchases: ";
    cin >> customer.numOfPurchases; 
    cout << "Enter Purchases: ";
    cin >> customer.purchases[0];
    cin >> customer.purchases[1];
    cin >> customer.purchases[2];
    cout << "Enter Type";
    getline(cin, customer.type);
    cout << endl;

    return in;
}

int Customer::getCustomerID()
{
    return customerID;
}

string Customer::getTitle()
{
    return title;
}

string Customer::getName()
{
    return name;
}

int Customer::getNumOfPurchases()
{
    return numOfPurchases;
}

int* Customer::getPurchases()
{
    return purchases;
}

string Customer::getType()
{
    return type;
}

void Customer::setCustomerID(int customerID)
{
    if (customerID < 1) {
        cout << "Customer ID has to be equal to 1 or more" << endl; //Changed all the "throw invalid_argument" messages to cout as they were causing an issue with my main.cpp file and an abort message kept appearing every time I ran my main.cpp file.
    }
    this->customerID = customerID;
}

void Customer::setTitle(string title)
{
    if (title.length() < 2) {
        cout << "Title has to be more than or equal to 2 characters" << endl;
    }
    this->title = title;
}

void Customer::setName(string name)
{
    if (name.length() < 4) {
        cout << "Length of name should be more than or equal to 4 characters" << endl;
    }
    this->name = name;
}

//Got help ith this on stack overflow as I was using "&&" instead of using "||" for the if statement
void Customer::setNumOfPurchases(int numOfPurchases)
{
    if(numOfPurchases <0 || numOfPurchases > 10000){
        cout << "Number of purchases should be between 0 to 10000" << endl;
    }
    this->numOfPurchases = numOfPurchases;
}

void Customer::setPurchases(int purchase1, int purchase2, int purchase3)
{
    if (purchase1 < 0 || purchase2 < 0 || purchase3 < 0) {
        cout << "Purchases must be more than or equal to zero" << endl;
    }
}

//Got help from stack overflow on comparing strings as I originally didnt use "type.compare"
void Customer::setType(string type) {
    if (type.compare("New") !=0 || type.compare("Either") !=0) {
        cout << "Type of purchase has to be New or Either" << endl;
    }
}
```

Text in my customers.txt file:

```
150034;Mr;Sean Brennan;New;5;365048;\n
150035;Mrs;Aisling Smith;Regular;6;375149;\n
150036;Mr;John Smith;New;7;385250;\n
150037;Mrs;Sharon Hanratty;Regular;8;395351;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218878/discussion-on-question-by-aisling-when-reading-in-a-txt-file-in-c-how-do-i-c).

Answer (score 1):

Trouble seems to be that you are trying to divide input into its hexadecimal digits and it looks like you are looking for decimal digits.
May be you can do something like following:

```
purchasesArray[0] = purchases / 10000;
purchasesArray[1] = (purchases / 100) % 100;
purchasesArray[2] = purchases % 100;
```

instead of

```
purchasesArray[0] = (purchases & (255 << 24)) >> 24;
purchasesArray[1] = (purchases & (255 << 16)) >> 16;
purchasesArray[2] = (purchases & (255 << 8)) >> 8;
```

Note: If your input is pretty big, above solution can be bad performancewise.

Note 2: Even if you really want hexadecimal digits, your parsing is problematic.

**Edit for note 2:**

To parse a 6 digit hexadecimal number you might do this:

```
purchasesArray[0] = (purchases & (255 << 16)) >> 16;
purchasesArray[1] = (purchases & (255 << 8)) >> 8;
purchasesArray[2] = purchases & 255;
```

your code seems to parse first 6 digits of an 8 digit hex number.
That is why I called it problematic.